# How to rearrage breadcrumbs in list page `2-column-left.phtml` alone?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, breadcrumbs, list.phtml

I want to display the `breadcrumbs`  under `col-main` `div` instead of `main` in list page alone. Not in all pages that uses the  `two-column-left` layout. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make following changes to the 2-columns-left.phtml

```
<?php $layout_handle = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles(); ?>
<?php if(in_array('catalog_category_view',$layout_handle)): ?>
    <div class="main">
        <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>
        <?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
            <div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first"><?php echo $_leftContent;   ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="col-main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="main">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>
        <?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
            <div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first"><?php echo $_leftContent;   ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="col-main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '(' ` is getting displayed.

Comment: I found  a solution. its not `elseif` its just `else`. if we use `elseif` we have to use another condition to check. And that is exactly the error indicates.